# How should I integrate the google map in my application?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-api

My Application is a php program, and I only have the address name, instead of the coordination on the map. But I find that the google map API requires the coordination to pin the address. How can I do so? Thank you.

I have the address:'觀塘%20牛頭角%20創業街%202號%20美亞工業大廈%202樓%202A%20202室'. 
It can be search, and pin on the google map application, but when I using the google api to do geocoding, it shows me ZERO_RESULT:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%E8%A7%80%E5%A1%98%20%E7%89%9B%E9%A0%AD%E8%A7%92%20%E5%89%B5%E6%A5%AD%E8%A1%97%202%E8%99%9F%20%E7%BE%8E%E4%BA%9E%E5%B7%A5%E6%A5%AD%E5%A4%A7%E5%BB%88&sensor=false

Comment: The process you are looking for is called Geocoding:  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: update the question with some geocoding problems.

Comment: Fixed with the params, region: Hong Kong.

Comment: Hmm. Strangely, it works  for me if I use the english translation: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Meyer%20Industrial%20Bldg%20Chong%20Yip%20St,%20Kwun%20Tong,%20Hong%20Kong&sensor=false is your incoming data UTF-8 encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the address into lat/lon first. You can either do this using javascript or you can use PHP (and cache it for later). Here is a simplified function to do that for you

```
function postcode_to_latlon($postcode){

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address='.$postcode);

    $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
    $lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;

    return array($lat, $lon);

}
```

This process is called geocoding.

Comment: But I got some problem, for example, I try to convert this address to the coordination like this: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=%E8%A7%80%E5%A1%98%20%E7%89%9B%E9%A0%AD%E8%A7%92%20%E5%89%B5%E6%A5%AD%E8%A1%97%202%E8%99%9F%20%E7%BE%8E%E4%BA%9E%E5%B7%A5%E6%A5%AD%E5%A4%A7%E5%BB%88%202%E6%A8%93%202A%20202%E5%AE%A4

Comment: It found nothing, but if I paste the address search from the google map, it can pin the address, like this: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%E8%A7%80%E5%A1%98%2520%E7%89%9B%E9%A0%AD%E8%A7%92%2520%E5%89%B5%E6%A5%AD%E8%A1%97%25202%E8%99%9F%2520%E7%BE%8E%E4%BA%9E%E5%B7%A5%E6%A5%AD%E5%A4%A7%E5%BB%88%25202%E6%A8%93%25202A%2520202%E5%AE%A4&hl=en&ie=UTF8&sll=0,0&sspn=141.573652,316.054688&vpsrc=6&hnear=Meyer+Industrial+Bldg,+2+Chong+Yip+St,+Hong+Kong&t=m&z=16

Comment: Try with http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=your_addr&flags=J&gflags=R&appid=your_app_key. it returns lat:22.319700, lon:114.223427. But you have to create an app key first.

Answer (score 0):

The address can't be found then. Try simplifying the address or switching things around so maybe Google will understand better. Also check for mistakes in your address string.

Comment: Fixed with the params, region: HK. I think google map web is assumed my application is used the hidden region HK. after I added the &region=HK everything work like magic.